# Unable to filter jobs by C#

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Attempting to filter jobs for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), actually ends up filtering jobs for [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

After having clicked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/135736/full-stack-net-developer-code-360) post, I then clicked on the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag which links me to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c#. Note that the URL is not escaping the `#`. The correct link should be https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c%23

Visiting that link redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c and adds [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) as the filter rather than [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)

Comment: If this doesn't get fixed I'm afraid you have to be come a C developer and so do I :( ....

Comment: Who downvoted this? I bet it was a Java dev...

Comment: This seems to be working now

Comment: I guess this is why I'm getting so much more recruiter emails -- none of the C# developers and find the jobs!

Comment: @rene you'd better learn c, sharp

Comment: @mattfreake Not for me

Comment: Did you try looking for d flat instead? Sometimes that can produce the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh URL encoding.

This is now fixed.

Thank you for your report!

Comment: Can you fix this for chat rooms too? :) For example: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c should be http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c%23

Comment: @TravisJ probably the wrong guy, he's working on jobs. You want balpha.

Comment: @TravisJ not really. Chat room names were always trimmed in the URL, by design. It's meaningless anyway, as there is unique ID for each room. It is the same as user profiles.

Comment: @Braiam see my comment, no need to involve any developer as this is not a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Fair point, was just curios since it seemed like a simple fix.