# Unable to re-order jobs filtered by C#

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-overflow-jobs, sorting

*This is related to but NOT the same as: [Unable to filter jobs by C#](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346354/unable-to-filter-jobs-by-c) That is related to just linking through by clicking on the 'c#' tag in listings, this is about re-ordering after getting to the page*

I was searching jobs on Stack Overflows jobs section. I viewed the 'C#' page at:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c%23

I then re-ordered the list to 'newest' using the drop-down shown here:

[image: The re-order drop-down]

But I was redirected to:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c?sort=p

Which shows 'C' jobs not 'C#' jobs, although the order is correct.

I looks like the encoded '#' is getting dropped on redirect when being redirected by the drop-down.

Manually adding the encoded '#' to the url https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c%23?sort=p does work, so it is not being lost when hitting the server.

*Tested on Firefox 55 and Chrome 61 on Windows 10 (1703)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wheee, so much fun with URL encoding! After battling through a legacy of crazy code it looks like this is finally fixed in *all* the places. .NET's `UriBuilder` is notoriously fussy about paths with various characters that you'd expect it to URL encode. Instead of treating them with the respect they deserve it maltreats them by acting like a `%23` is a `#`. It then proceeds to think that the `#` is the fragment part of the URL. Sad :(

Thanks for the heads up, the fix is now pushed to production.

Comment: Ive been bitten with `UriBuilder` too, so totally understand. My last major project was a custom "single sign on" solution, so LOTS of redirects and UriBuilder caused alot of the headaches lol. Thanks for the fix